# Фоновое изображение у текста

Tags: html, css, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Коротко: как сделать фоновое изображение у текста?

Длинно: представьте себе, вы скотчем выложите на стекле окна (окно в доме) буквы АБВ, а потом покрасите стекло, не раму, а стекло, и потом снимите скотч. Получится АБВ, и у этих букв фон, фон - это пейзаж за окном. Вот охота сделать на странице в белом заголовке определенное слово (которое может буду менять), и охота вместо цвета букв сделать всему слову (или отдельно каждой букве) фон... ну или текстуру. Как так сделать?

Это возможно? Кто-нибудь такое делал?

p.s. В идеале охота, что-то связанное с JS, причем не отдельным файлом, а "все внутри" страницы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<p id="text" style="font-size:30px;font-family:Arial">text 8 ЛВЛ text text</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('text');
var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
cvs.width = el.clientWidth;
cvs.height = el.clientHeight;
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.font = el.style.fontSize + ' ' + el.style.fontFamily;
    var ptn = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    ctx.fillStyle = ptn;
    ctx.fillText(el.innerHTML, 0, cvs.height);
    el.innerHTML = '';
    el.appendChild(cvs);
}
img.src = 'step9addlight.jpg';

</script>
```

Это грубый набросок. Надеюсь, основная мысль ясна. =)

Comment: интересная штуковина

Answer (score 1):

Нормальный:

1. файл - пнгшка с прозрачными буквами(алфавит), но непрозрачным фоном. Минус - постоянный размер шрифта. При изменении размера шрифта надо менять файл.
   Полуизвратский:
2. SVG+VRML - создаем векторные изображения шрифта. Можно конвертером.
   Минус - в старых браузерах ничего видно не будет.
   Извратский:
3. Дивами же! =) Попиксельно. А ниче смешного: артлебедев так круглую "лупу" собрал. Ниче, не жалуется. Минус: ИЕ6 загнется от такого числа элементов.
   Флэшовый:
4. Flash/Silverlight. Второй - предпочтительнее. Минусы: че-то еще качать надо. Много весит сама штука.